# Case insensitive to joins table [active record]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these two tables:

**product** has_one **address**

**address** belongs_to **product**

When I want to find a product from one city, I do:

```
Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {city: @city})
```

But now I want to find a city with case insensitive. How can I do ?

I tried some ways and nothing:

```
Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {"lower(city) like ?", @city.downcase})

Product.all.joins(:address).where(addresses: {"lower(city) like ?": @city.downcase})
```

Obs: this question is not duplicated. I'm not asking about case insensitive but case insentive from column of another table which is not working.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, once you go to using the string form of `where` - you need to supply the table name yourself in the string, so `where( "LOWER(addresses.city) ...` or however you approach it.

Comment: Hi @smathy, what you suggest ? Product.all.joins(:address).where("LOWER(addresses.city)", @city.downcase) doesn't work...

Comment: Please, remove the 'duplicated' tag

Comment: See the "..." in what I wrote above, I've only included part of what you need, read the other answer it has everything you need to know other than adding the table name.